# how to perform postback inside success function of jquery

Tags: jquery, postback

I am Having input type button with attributes `id=btnok` and I call `jQuery` function on click of button using

```
$("#btnok").click(function { 

})
```

and `ajax` request inside that function.

I want to post back inside of success function of that `ajax` request or after calling of that function.

Comment: When you say "post back", are you talking about ASP.NET WebForms postbacks, or simply submitting a form?

Comment: A quick glance at the manual should solve your problem: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for reply..@HackedByChinese I just want to Asp.net WebForms Postback

Answer (score 0):

You would do so in your .ajax call, or in this example below, your `get()` call, just my preference to use `get()` for ajax requests:

```
 $("#btnok").click(function(){

      $.get(url,function(data){
        //your post back function goes here
      });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need an success and failed callback you can do it:

```
$("#btnok").click(function {     
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "url",
        success: function (data) {
            // all good
        },
        error: function (data) {
            // error
        }
    });
});
```